vue js library vue-json-excel3
currently I'm using the library vue-json-excel3
and I'm getting some issues when I try to export .xls
I have this json:
data = [
  {
    "id_operation": "X34568983",
    "crid": "092CR30910",
    "t_beneficiary": "1/3",
    "reference": "000000161408",
    "date": "2024-03-12 11:45:35",
  }
]

I add format before create .xls
const formattedData = computed(() => {
  const filteredItems = filteredData.value;

  return filteredItems.map((item:any) => {  
    return { 
      ...item, 
      t_beneficiary: `'${item.t_beneficiary}`, 
      reference: `'${item.reference}`, 
      date: dayjs(item.date).format("YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm:ss"), 
    };
  });
});

I add this caracter ' because the excel don't take the correct value, so, when I try to create the excel file I get:

if I remove the caracter ' I get:

there some way to create a excel with correct format?
I just want get this:

it's possible?

Questions regarding small third party libraries are probably better asked on the library's github where the maintainer can answer.  Actually, the question has already been asked.
